# spring security + form login + redis session storage -> keep coming out anonymous User

Tags: session, spring-security, redis, storage, httpsession

I have been struggling for days because after logging in and receiving the welcome message, the user appears as an anonymous user when moving to another browser page.
I confirmed that sessions are stored inside Redis. However, I keep getting errors indicating that something other than the SecurityContext is being stored in HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.

Also It shows that a LinkedHashMap is stored inside the SpringSecurityContextHolder.

I've also tried searching on Google, but I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for. I'm not sure what the cause is.

```
// build.gradle
'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test'
```

this is the session stored in redis

```
{
  "creationTime": 1711475749704,
  "lastAccessedTime": 1711475904642,
  "maxInactiveInterval": 1800,
  "sessionAttr": {
    "SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT": {
      "authentication": {
        "authorities": [
          {
            "authority": "ROLE_ADMIN"
          }
        ],
        "details": {
          "remoteAddress": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
          "sessionId": "96f82b5f-49ee-4518-9f3a-da58f6212f7b"
        },
        "authenticated": true,
        "principal": {
          "password": null,
          "username": "sejinpark@email.com",
          "authorities": [
            {
              "authority": "ROLE_ADMIN"
            }
          ],
          "accountNonExpired": true,
          "accountNonLocked": true,
          "credentialsNonExpired": true,
          "enabled": true
        },
        "credentials": null,
        "name": "sejinpark@email.com"
      }
    },
    "SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST": {
      "cookies": [
        {
          "name": "Idea-571775cc",
          "value": "4869c9df-2414-4603-b718-76027a1adc42",
          "attributes": {
            "Max-Age": "-1",
            "Secure": "false"
          },
          "version": 0,
          "path": null,
          "domain": null,
          "maxAge": -1,
          "comment": null,
          "secure": false,
          "httpOnly": false
        },
        {
          "name": "SESSION",
          "value": "YTYwZTlmMGUtZDA2YS00YTBlLTgxZTYtYzg0ZjlmYjZmNzdi",
          "attributes": {
            "Max-Age": "-1",
            "Secure": "false"
          },
          "version": 0,
          "path": null,
          "domain": null,
          "maxAge": -1,
          "comment": null,
          "secure": false,
          "httpOnly": false
        }
      ],
      "locales": [
        "ko_KR",
        "ko",
        "en_US",
        "en"
      ],
      "contextPath": "",
      "method": "GET",
      "pathInfo": null,
      "queryString": null,
      "requestURI": "/error",
      "requestURL": "http://localhost:8080/error",
      "scheme": "http",
      "serverName": "localhost",
      "servletPath": "/error",
      "serverPort": 8080,
      "parameterMap": {},
      "headerNames": [
        "accept",
        "accept-encoding",
        "accept-language",
        "connection",
        "cookie",
        "host",
        "sec-ch-ua",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform",
        "sec-fetch-dest",
        "sec-fetch-mode",
        "sec-fetch-site",
        "sec-fetch-user",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests",
        "user-agent"
      ],
      "parameterNames": [],
      "redirectUrl": "http://localhost:8080/error?continue"
    }
  }
}
```

1. When attempting to log in, the log shows that authentication was successful.
   [success login security log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85n6K.png)
2. When retrieving the authenticated user, the log indicates the process.
   [can't not found authenticated user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNYg6.png)

```
20240327 10:34:08.466 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext is in unnamed module of loader 'app')] with root cause 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I've been continuously modifying the SecurityConfig and trying to apply filters, but I'm still not sure what the problem is.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final AuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    private final AuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    private final AccessDeniedHandler customAccessDeniedHandler;
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/api/v1/members/login";

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(headerConfig ->
                        headerConfig.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable)
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers(
                                        PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()
                                ).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(
                                        "/",
                                        "/api/v1/members/signup",
                                        "/main",
                                        "/api/v1/sse/**",
                                        "/api/v1/event/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(
                                        "/member").hasAnyRole("USER")
                                .requestMatchers("/admin").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        http
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_URL)
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/api/v1/")
                        .usernameParameter("email")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                        .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                        .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                        .permitAll()
                );
        http
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/api/v1/members/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl(LOGIN_URL)
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("SESSIONID")
                );
        http
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling
                        .accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler)
                );
        http.
                rememberMe(rememberMe -> rememberMe
                        .rememberMeCookieName("remember")
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                );
        http
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .maximumSessions(1)
                        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
                        .expiredUrl(LOGIN_URL)
                )
                .securityContext((securityContext) -> {
                   securityContext.securityContextRepository(delegatingSecurityContextRepository());
                    securityContext.requireExplicitSave(true);
                });
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncryptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DelegatingSecurityContextRepository delegatingSecurityContextRepository() {
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        );
    }
}
```